# Threejs update objects position when animating (Blender export, morph animation)

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, three.js

I've got an exported animation from blender loaded into my scene. What I’m trying to achieve is to click the object, the object animated 50% the way through it's keyframes and stops, then if I click the object again the remaining 50% of keyframes are iterated over.

So far I have the object animating to 50%. The issue is that no intersection is found in the click eventhandler.

```
function mousedown( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    // update mouse object
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // find intersections

    // create a reay with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );

    var ray = projector.pickingRay( vector.clone(), camera );

    //Check for intersections
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList , true);

    // if there is one (or more) intersections
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        console.log(intersects);
        //Start animating - animation is a global var in this scene triggering
        //the animation.
        animation = true;

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No intersections");        
    }

}
```

This works when the object is first instantiated. It doesn't work after the object has 'been animated' though. After some debugging I can see that even after the object has moved (the first 50% of the animation has played through) the object's geometry's position = (0, 0, 0).

Which seems to make sense as to why the mousedown event isn't picking up an intersection, as in the 'world' the object isn't actually positioned where it seems to be on the screen.

Here's the code for loading the object:

```
jsonLoader.load("assets/models/cheese01.js", function(geometry){
    geometry.computeMorphNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals(); 
    // geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    // geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true; 
    // verticesNeedUpdate = true; 

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xaa1100,
        morphTargets: true,
        morphNormals: true,
        wrapAround: true
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    mesh.duration = 3000;
    mesh.time = 0;
    mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

    mesh.rotation.x = degToRad(175);

    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mesh.updateMatrix();

    geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;

    mesh.parseAnimations();

    scene.add(mesh);
    //Objects subject to intersection checks (from mouse click)
    targetList.push(mesh);
    //Objects to animate
    morphs.push(mesh);

 });
```

Cheers in advance for any help!